# Rundeck: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: java, grails, ssl, smtp, rundeck

I'm going crazy with rundeck and this grails configuration for mail, I'm trying to connect to my smtp server running STARTSSL on 587 (self signed cert) here is my configuration:

```
grails.mail.host=smtp.myhost.com
grails.mail.port=587
grails.mail.username=username
grails.mail.password=password
grails.mail.smtp.auth="true"
grails.mail.starttls.enable=true
grails.mail.props["mail.smtp.auth":"true","mail.smtp.starttls.enable":"true","mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"587"``,"mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory","mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false,"mail.smtp.port":"587"]
grails.mail.default.from=rundeck@myhost.com
```

I read all the issues about it on Stack Overflow but without result...

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `grails.mail.props` in rundeck-config.properties won't work, you have to convert to groovy format.

See these links:

- http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/email-settings.html#advanced-smtp-settings
- https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/wiki/Faq#how-do-i-configure-a-smtp-server-for-email-notifications

Here is an example:

```
grails {
  mail {
    host="smtp.gmail.com"
    port="465"
    username="rundecktest@gmail.com"
    password="..."
    props=["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
  }
}
grails.mail.default.from="rundecktest@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Do you need to convert the whole rundeck-config.properties to groovy in order to work?

Comment: No. You should create a separate file with just SMTP settings in /etc/rundeck/ dir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601574/rundeck-gmail-smtp-not-working/63922280#63922280  For Rundeck inside a Docker container: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76058536/11130638