# Rundeck Gmail SMTP not Working - smtp.gmail.com Unknown Host

Tags: smtp, rundeck

I want to configure Rundeck to allow e-mail notifications.

My `rundeck-config.properties` is:

```
grails.mail.host = "smtp.gmail.com"
grails.mail.username = "name@domain.com"
grails.mail.port = 465
grails.mail.password = "******"
grails.mail.props = ["mail.smtp.starttls.enable":"true","mail.smtp.auth":"true","mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465","mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
```

When I run the Job, the error I get is:

```
2016-05-05 14:49:30,557 ERROR NotificationService - Error sending notification email to me@gmail.com for Execution 11: Mail ser
ver connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: "smtp.gmail.com", 465; ti
meout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.UnknownHostException: "smtp.gmail.com". Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
port: "smtp.gmail.com", 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.UnknownHostException: "smtp.gmail.com"
```

I tried everything I could find on Google but the error keeps the same.

I also tried to `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` and it works

Could someone help me?

Comment: Try sending a sample mail through sendmail and check if your server can sendout mails using 465... Try 587 or 25 too because some ISP will block some ports, however 465 should have gone through..

Comment: @LeoPrince, how can I test the "sendmail"? Is it within Rundeck? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Sendmail not necessary, you can check it using mail command. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-write-command-to-send-receive-mail/

Comment: @LucasRezende I have some issue. did you find any solution for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You Must need to use .groovy file as props is not supported in .properties file

below is my rundeck-config.groovy file which is working fine

```
loglevel.default="INFO"
rdeck.base="/var/lib/rundeck"
rss.enabled=false

dataSource.dbCreate = "update"
dataSource.url = "jdbc:h2:file:/var/lib/rundeck/data/rundeckdb;MVCC=true;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4"
grails {
  mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        username = "************"
        port = 587
        password = "*********"
        props = ["mail.smtp.starttls.enable":"true","mail.smtp.auth":"true","mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"587","mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
  }
}
grails.serverURL="http://***.***.***.***:4440"
```

Reference: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1607

- https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/wiki/Faq#how-do-i-configure-a-smtp-server-for-email-notifications
- https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/wiki/Faq#how-do-i-convert-my-rundeck-config-file-to-groovy
- https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/wiki/Faq#how-do-i-specify-a-new-config-file-location